# [spring security oauth]access_denied:Expected CSRF token not found

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

I practice spring security oauth2 with client credentials grant type
Here is my xml files for spring security oauth

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">


    <sec:debug />
    <oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
        <oauth:client-credentials />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider
            user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService">
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
            parameters -->
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
            before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
        resource-id="rest_server" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
        <oauth:client client-id="abc" authorized-grant-types="client_credentials"
            authorities="ROLE_RESTREAD" secret="123" />
    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <http pattern="/**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/prot**" access="ROLE_RESTREAD"
            method="GET" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>




    <bean id="tokenStore"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />


    <bean id="tokenServices"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="false" />
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="400000" />
        <property name="refreshTokenValiditySeconds" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="theRealm" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="theRealm/client" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />


    <sec:global-method-security
        pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
        <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    </sec:global-method-security>

    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

</beans>
```

And I test on mac terminal :

```
curl -X -v -d 'client_id=abc&client_secret=123&grant_type=client_credentials' -X POST "http://localhost:8080/WiBDA_User/oauth/token"
```

But got error :

```
{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?"}
```

Please tell me what's wrong??
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> As of Spring Security 4.0, CSRF protection is enabled by default with XML configuration. If you would like to disable CSRF protection, the corresponding XML configuration can be seen below.
>
> ```
> <http>
>   <csrf disabled="true"/>
> </http>
> ```

Source : http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-configure

**UPDATE** : Please update your code to the new java-config, it is easy to understand and configure.

Comment: sorry I'm new in java what is ````new java-config````?

Comment: read this :http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc and if you like the visuals view this :: www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4BQXNufpbQ